# Permissions on new created files (Windows 7 specific)?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, cacls, icacls

Maybe a noob question, but how ALCs are determined on new created files (by running MyApp.exe)? I'd like to grant "users" full control on new files created inside C:\ProgramData\MyApp when launching myapp.exe. However this is not working:

```
icacls "%ProgramData%\MyApp" /grant "Users":(OI)(CI)F
echo "" >> "%ProgramData%\MyApp\test.txt"
```

test.txt of course has right permissions (full control by users group). However when i run MyApp.exe it creates a tons of files in "%ProgramData%\MyApp" but **without any ACLs information**.

Where i'm wrong? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CreateFile()` Win32 API allows specifying a custom security descriptor to be applied for new files. It could be that the author of MyApp, instead of using `NULL`, specified a valid but empty descriptor, resulting in the lack of ACLs.